# Which one of these 2 sentences is correct?

Tags: grammar

There are no longer big public parks in the city center like we used to have 10 years ago

There are no longer big public parks in the city center like there were 10 years ago

If both are correct, which one is better?

Comment: Both appear to be valid syntax/semantics.  Which is "better" is a matter of opinion/context.

Comment: In my *opinion*, you should use "There are no longer big public parks like we used to have in the city center 10 years ago."

Comment: Can't it be, "There are no longer big public parks in the city center than those we used to have 10 years ago." ? It's like 'longer...than'.

Comment: Please, migrate this question to ell.stackexchange.com .

Comment: @RamPillai -- Your use of "than" is incorrect (relative to the rest of the sentence).

Comment: @johann_ka how to migrate?